# Calculate a numeric value of a histogram?

Tags: php, image-processing, histogram

I need to compare 2 different histograms of 2 different images (to search for similar images)

How could I get a numeric value of the histogram so I can do something like:

```
if ( (image1.histogram_value - image2.histogram_value) < threshold )
 //> images are similar !
```

### Note:

I need a single value because I need to store it in a database, so I can fast compare thousands images.

Comment: A histogram is already a hugely condensed description of an image. I doubt you can condense it into a single value and still retain anything meaningful. Perhaps what you really want to ask is how to compare two histograms?

Comment: @MarkRansom: the problem is I need to fast compare thousands images. I have a database of images, and for each images I store this value so i can fast compare new images

Comment: Just because you want something doesn't mean it's possible.

Comment: Do you have any constraints on storage? If you only want to compare images fast, it doesn't require storing a single value. Histograms can be stored in a k-d tree or similar structure, take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use histogram similarity measures to compare two histograms. Otherwise, using a single number to represent a histogram is not meaningfull, unless your histogram is always a well known density function with a single parameter (which is not the case with arbitrary images).

So you can use one of the following measures (among many others):

- Bhattacharya coefficient
- Euclidian distance

Comment: Consider in my database I have thousands of images. I need a value that can be comparable with a new one, otherwise the search is too slow

Comment: You can try decreasing number of bins in your histograms. Also there are more advanced methods such as Multi-Scale Histograms (http://www.springerlink.com/content/739669y5uchg2lh7/) for improving performance.  Please don't get me wrong, but representing the whole image with a single number just don't make sense. I mean you can do it, but then it will not contain enough information to do anything with it.